# How to setup the windows "window time" service so the service will always synchronize the time after startup?

Tags: windows, windows-10, time

Currently on windows 10 the startup type is "automatic (trigger start)" for "windows time", but every time I start in windows the time is in UTC and not the local time. So every time after booting up windows I have to go to "Adjust time/date" and click on "sync now".

I would like to have that this sync is automatically run after each bootup of windows 10. How can I achieve this ambitious goal?

Comment: I don't think so. My question is about a server time sync, not BIOS related...

Comment: Your system is unintentionally set to UTC and I suspect it’s due to the registry key in question.

Comment: Ok thanks, I tried to set that reg entry and so far it seems to work. I will keep an eye ...